# Problem in Reactive Forms - Type 'FormGroup' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my ts I have written a function:

```
// Form
summaryAreaForm = new FormGroup ({
    summary: new FormControl(null)
  })

// Function
update() {
    document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML = this.summaryAreaForm('summary').value;
  }
```

In the last part `this.summaryAreaForm('summary').value` the error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'FormGroup' has no compatible call signatures.` is output to me. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't really be using `document.getElementById` or similar when using angular.

To resolve this issue, I believe you should be using:

```js
this.summaryAreaForm.get('summary').value;
```