# Angular 14: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')

Tags: angular

Need to compare two fields' values, validation is put into 2nd field's validation.

HTML:

```html
    <form [formGroup]="fg">
        F1: <input type="text" class=".." formControlName="f1" id="f1" (blur)="b($event)" .../>
        F2: <input type="text" class=".." formControlName="f2" id="f2" .../>
    </form>
```

TS:

```js
    import {  FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    export class c implements OnInit 
    {
        public fg!: FormGroup;   // another SO's accepted answer to tell ng not init yet.
        public b1: number = 0;
        
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)    // same error if "public" to "private", or moving content into ngOnInit()
        {
            this.fg = this.fb.group(
            {
                f1: ['', [Validators.required]] ,
                f2: ['', [Validators.required, this.compare1n2()]]
            }      
        );
        
        private compare1n2()
        {
            // runtime complains about this line, same for .get('f1')
            const v1 = this.fg.controls['f1'].value;    
            
            return (control: FormControl) =>
            {
                const v2 = control.value || '';
                return (v1 != v2) ? {bad: 1} : null;  // workaround is to compare with b1.
            }
        }
        
        public b(e: any) {this.b1 = this.fg.controls['f1'].value; // ok too .get('f1').value
    }
```

Everything works well except 1st line of `compare1n2()`. I've studied and used answers from [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616242/5063031), and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62810660/5063031).

Change `this.fg = this.fb.group({...})` to below,

```js
    this.fg = new FormGroup(
    {
        f1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]) ,
        f2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.compare1n2()])
    }
```

still the same **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that line inside the callback function and check if f1 has actually been initialized before using it.

```js
  private compare1n2() {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      if (!this.fg?.controls || !this.fg.controls['f1']) return null;
      const v1 = this.fg.controls['f1'].value;
      const v2 = control.value || '';
      return v1 != v2 ? { bad: 1 } : null;
    };
  }
```

It seems that the validators are called once *during* initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public fg: FormGroup = new this.fb.group( { f1: ['', [Validators.required]] , f2: ['', [Validators.required, this.compare1n2()]] }
```

Comment: `'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have any compilation error on this line of the code :

```
const v1 = this.fg.control['f1'].value;
```

I don't think fg would have a property/method name as 'control'. It should be 'controls' ( plural) same as you used in first line of methond 'b'.

Please review.

Comment: typo corrected. thanks